# Show that a finite $T_0$-space has at least one point which is a closed subset

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Show that a finite $T_0$-space has at least one point which is a closed subset.

I'm trying to read through the first chapter of this text "Finite Spaces and Larger Contexts" by J. Peter May to get ideas for an undergraduate research project.  This is the first exercise he puts to the reader and already I'm a bit lost on this proof (though he does mention it would be challenging for the novice).

Comment: Hint: If the space is $\lbrace x_1, \dots, x_n \rbrace$ take $x_1$ and ask : Does $x_2$ belongs to an open set such that $x_1$ does not?.  Repeat the procedure, if the answer is yes for every point then $x_1$ is a closed subset.

Comment: Ok here's where I'm confused.  According to wikipedia this set:
$\{\emptyset, \{c\}, \{b, c\}, \{a, b, c\}$  is $T_0$

So $\{c\}$ should be a closed set.  But the complement of $\{c\} (\{a, b\})$ doesn't seem to be an open set in X.

Comment: Set is $T_0$? What does that mean.

Comment: @Jakobian are you confused about how I wrote my comment or are you trying to lead me to a realization?  I can't tell.

Comment: I'm confused by what you wrote. We say a topological space is $T_0$. Moreover, you wrote $\{c\}$ is closed, which is confusing since one would thing the family you wrote is a topology.

Comment: Sorry I very rarely post here it's a challenge for sure!  My understanding of the definition of a closed set is that the complement of the set is open and so should be an element of the topology.  In the set {∅,{c},{b,c},{a,b,c}} which is a topology on {a,b,c},  {c} doesn't look like a closed set by that definition?

Comment: What's the family you wrote? If it's topology given to $X = \{a, b, c\}$ then $\{c\}$ is open by definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133657/discussion-between-zachary-and-jakobian).

Comment: @Zachary The set $\{a,b,c\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset,\{c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ is $T_0$, as the Wikipedia says. That doesn't contradicts what you are trying to prove: There exists at least one point (in this case $\{a\}$) that is closed.

Comment: @jjagmath  Thank you!  I'm very new to topology just taking intro now.  For some reason I got mixed up and was thinking the closed subset had to be an element of the topology on X rather than simply any subset of X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\leq y$ when $x\in \overline{\{y\}}$.

This is a transitive relation on $X$, and $T_0$ axiom means that $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ implies $x = y$. So it makes $X$ into a partially ordered set.

The set $\{x\}$ being closed in $X$ means that if $y\leq x$ then $y = x$, that is $x$ is a minimal element of $X$.

But a finite (non-empty) poset has a minimal element.

Comment: Also does the bar over {y} refer to the closure of that set?

Comment: Yes, the bar means closure